# Get ZipCode from City using PHP or JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, symfony

is it possible to get one ZipCode or array of all ZipCodes or something similar knowling only the City/Country? For Example, user write: Madrid, Spain and I get also zip code like 15304 or all the zip codes...

Using PHP or JavaScript or JQuery...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use an API. USPS has one that can be used here: https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/welcome.htm

Answer (score 1):

There are different API's which supports looking up ZIP codes based on address. For example [LiveAddress API](http://smartystreets.com/products/liveaddress-api).